# Is Exchange User Out of Office?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, exchange, powershell-3.0

[Finding Users Who Have "Out Of Office" Enabled In Exchange 2010](http://msunified.net/2009/12/07/finding-users-who-have-%E2%80%9Cout-of-office%E2%80%9D-enabled-in-exchange-2010/) describes how to use PowerShell to determine if a user has his/her out-of-office setting enabled.  However, it requires the use of the [Exchange Management Shell](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6268).

Is there a way to do this without installing (additional) dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

Compose an e-mail to that user.  When Outlook resolves the name (or e-mail address) to the Exchange account, any Automatic (Out Of Office) Replies will show above the "To:" field.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Simple, but effective.